# Knockout.js Extending value binding with interceptor

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, knockout-2.0, knockout-validation

This seems to be a common approach to sanitizing/validating/formatting data with knockout when binding to an input field, it creates a reusable custom binding that uses a computed observable. It basically extends the default value binding to include an interceptor that will format/sanitize/validate input before written/read.

```
ko.bindingHandlers.amountValue = {
  init: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor) {
    var underlyingObservable = valueAccessor();

    var interceptor = ko.computed({
      read: function () {
        // this function does get called, but it's return value is not used as the value of the textbox.
        // the raw value from the underlyingObservable is still used, no dollar sign added. It seems like 
        // this read function is completely useless, and isn't used at all
        return "$" + underlyingObservable();
      },

      write: function (newValue) {
        var current = underlyingObservable(),
            valueToWrite = Math.round(parseFloat(newValue.replace("$", "")) * 100) / 100;

        if (valueToWrite !== current) {
          // for some reason, if a user enters 20.00000 for example, the value written to the observable
          // is 20, but the original value they entered (20.00000) is still shown in the text box.
          underlyingObservable(valueToWrite);
        } else {
          if (newValue !== current.toString())
            underlyingObservable.valueHasMutated();
        }
      }
    });

    ko.bindingHandlers.value.init(element, function () { return interceptor }, allBindingsAccessor);
  },

  update: ko.bindingHandlers.value.update
};
```

jsFiddle example: http://jsfiddle.net/6wxb5/1/

Am i missing something? I've seen this method used everywhere, but it doesn't seem to fully work. The read function seems completely useless as it doesn't get used at all.., and in the write function, entering "23.0000" changes the written value to 23, but the textbox values do not update.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The issue comes from the `update` portion of your custom binding.  This part will update the field based on the original model value.  So, the event handler attached in the `init` will send the new value through your writeable computed, but the updating of the field actually happens in the `update`.

One option is to apply the value binding from your `init` function and skip the `update` function like:

```
ko.bindingHandlers.amountValue = {
  init: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor) {
    var underlyingObservable = valueAccessor();

    var interceptor = ko.computed({
      read: function () {
        // this function does get called, but it's return value is not used as the value of the textbox.
        // the raw value from the underlyingObservable, or the actual value the user entered is used instead, no   
        // dollar sign added. It seems like this read function is completely useless, and isn't used at all
        return "$" + underlyingObservable();
      },

      write: function (newValue) {
        var current = underlyingObservable(),
            valueToWrite = Math.round(parseFloat(newValue.replace("$", "")) * 100) / 100;

        if (valueToWrite !== current) {
          // for some reason, if a user enters 20.00000 for example, the value written to the observable
          // is 20, but the original value they entered (20.00000) is still shown in the text box.
          underlyingObservable(valueToWrite);
        } else {
          if (newValue !== current.toString())
            underlyingObservable.valueHasMutated();
        }
      }
    });

      ko.applyBindingsToNode(element, { value: interceptor });
  }
};
```

Updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/rniemeyer/Sr8Ev/

Comment: Thanks, that was frustrating ;)